# Encryption in C# and IOS using SHA1

Tags: c#, ios, encryption, hash

C# code.

```
SHA1 hash = SHA1.Create();
ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] combined = encoder.GetBytes(password);
hash.ComputeHash(combined);
passwordHash = Convert.ToBase64String(hash.Hash);
```

How can I get the same result in IOS? Please Help me.

So far I've done this much but the result is different than C#

```
NSString *password = @"XABCVKXMWJ"; // your password

CFIndex asciiLength;
// Determine length of converted data:
CFStringGetBytes((__bridge CFStringRef)(password), CFRangeMake(0, [password length]),
                 kCFStringEncodingASCII, '?', false, NULL, 0, &asciiLength);
// Allocate buffer:
uint8_t *asciiBuffer = malloc(asciiLength);
// Do the conversion:
CFStringGetBytes((__bridge CFStringRef)(password), CFRangeMake(0, [password length]),
                 kCFStringEncodingASCII, '?', false, asciiBuffer, asciiLength, NULL);
unsigned char hash[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CC_SHA1(asciiBuffer, asciiLength, hash);
free(asciiBuffer);
NSData *result = [NSData dataWithBytes:hash length:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
```

The result I am getting from C# code is 
uSFCLAZZHkBVN7xViO3hKkhhR/s=

and from IOS, it is
uSFCLAZZHkBVN7xViO3hKkhhR+s=

Comment: Just a side note: hashing is _not_ encryption!

Comment: You can use the CommonCrypto library on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS result is correct, there is some difference between C# and iOS, possibly `combined` is different. Verify the intermediate values at each step in the C# code, see all the intermediate values in the sample code below.

Here is my Objective-C implementation which produces the same result as yours.
Note: There is no need to use Core Foundation or `malloc`.

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>

NSString *password = @"XABCVKXMWJ";

NSData *combined = [password dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableData *hash = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CC_SHA1(combined.bytes, (unsigned int)combined.length, hash.mutableBytes);
NSString *passwordHash = [hash base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

NSLog(@"password:     %@", password);
NSLog(@"combined:     %@", combined);
NSLog(@"hash:         %@", hash);
NSLog(@"passwordHash: %@", passwordHash);
```

Output:

```
password:     XABCVKXMWJ
combined:     58414243564b584d574a
hash:         b921422c06591e405537bc5588ede12a486147eb
passwordHash: uSFCLAZZHkBVN7xViO3hKkhhR+s=
```